# Cannot get NET SHARE to work with spaced variables

Tags: batch-file, share, wmic

I am trying to write a batch file that goes over existing network shares and deletes all the non-administrative ones.

Here's my code:

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ SKIP=1 TOKENS=*"  %%j IN (`wmic /node:192.168.0.101 SHARE WHERE "Name like '%%[^$]'" GET NAME ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) DO NET SHARE %%j /DELETE
```

`SKIP=1`for skipping meta-column information on wmic return

`findstr /r /v "^$"` for removing a trailing whiteline from wmic return which was getting captured in `%%j`

Now, this only works for share names that do not contain a space in-between.

To remedy, I have tried (which doesn't work as well):

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ SKIP=1 TOKENS=*"  %%j IN (`wmic /node:192.168.0.101 SHARE WHERE "Name like '%%[^$]'" GET NAME ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) DO NET SHARE "%%j" /DELETE
```

Further, trying to echo the `%%j` variable in quotes resulted in this:

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ SKIP=1 TOKENS=*"  %%j IN (`wmic /node:192.168.0.101 SHARE WHERE "Name like '%%[^$]'" GET NAME ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) DO @ECHO "%%j"
```

[image: Only single quotes present]

Where only single quotes got printed

Kindly help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all of that with a single `WMIC` command, without a `For` loop and without the need to involve `FindStr` or the `Share` option of `net.exe`:

```bash
@%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe /Node:192.168.0.101 Share Where "Type < 2147483648" Call Delete
```

Comment: Can you pls explain what does "Type < 2147483648" do?

Comment: It selects all shares which are not of type `Disk Drive Admin`, `Print Queue Admin`, `Device Admin`, or `IPC Admin`; i.e. Non administrative, _(your stated goal)_. You can see that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-share), and can first check which are selected using the `Name` property of `Get`; i.e. ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe /Node:192.168.0.101 Share Where "Type < 2147483648" Get Name```.

Comment: ty, I tried executing. Get name accurately is fetching all the non-admin shares but the call delete command fails with the following: Method execution successful. Out Parameters: instance of __PARAMETERS { ReturnValue = 2; };"

Comment: Well if you bothered to read up on the [delete method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/delete-method-in-class-win32-share), you'd see that the return value `2` is 'access denied'. You can only delete shares if you have the appropriate permissions. To clarify, that is not a problem with my code.

Comment: My bad. I did figure out that I was having cmd elevation issues but forgot to update in the thread. Marking your answer as the one I was looking for. Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

`wmic` for some insane reason outputs end of line with *two* CR's: CR CR LF. Windows including FINDSTR and CMD only takes CR LF as end of line and leaves the other CR as part of the data, so `echo "somestuff     <CR>"` produces a display with `"` only in the leftmost column. In W10 (and I assume 11) if you redirect to a file and open it in notepad you will see it interprets these as 'Macintosh (CR)' linebreaks.

Windows tools aren't generally flexible in dealing with unexpected control characters. The only way I can find, in a CMD/batch file, is the delayedexpansion trick:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "USEBACKQ SKIP=1 TOKENS=*"  %%j IN (`wmic ...`) DO @(SET "X=%%j" & ECHO {!X:~0,-1!})
```

However you will quickly see this leaves a bunch of trailing spaces (also) output by `wmic`, which causes e.g. `net share "blah blah      " /delete` to fail, and I don't know any way to remove the trailing spaces while keeping embedded ones that you want.

If you instead use powershell's `(get-smbshare).name` you don't have either problem (no extra CR and no extra spaces, also no header line and no empty line to bother with). But if you use powershell you can use its filtering also and do the whole job in one command:

```
remove-smbshare ((get-smbshare).name -notmatch "\$") -force
```

and this is no longer the question you asked.

Comment: 1) Why are share names with no spaces in between working fine (as they should have the <CR> at the end too)?
2) Can you explain in brief what ECHO {!X:~0,-1!} is doing?